# Java: Json in a Heroku project

Tags: java, json, postgresql, heroku

I'm exploring a very simple way: creating a simple server:

```
public class SimpleServer {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ServerSocket s = null;
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        s = new ServerSocket(9999);
        System.out.println("Server started, listen on "
        + "port 9999");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            Socket s1 = s.accept();

            OutputStream s1out = s1.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter
            (new OutputStreamWriter(s1out));
            bw.write("Hi client, This is Server!");
            System.out.println("messagge sent to " +
            s1.getInetAddress()+"--"+
            s1.getInputStream()+"--"
           );


            bw.close();
            s1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

But I don't know how to read the header/body information!
 Consider that I have to receive a http-post request, and all I need is read the info (they are in json format)

> I have a web-based software that pushes a json file to a URL (post).
>   In Heroku (dev in Java), I need to:
>
> - specify the URL
> - receive the json
> - write the content on PostgreSQL
>
> I am pretty new to JAVA and heroku, I'm studying night and day but I
>   need a little help!
>
> Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some code you have tried and a specific problem / error that arose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If Heroku provides a full Java EE 6 runtime:

Receive the JSON with JAX-RS - create a POJO with methods that model your REST-like service, annotate them with JAX-RS annotations like `@Path`, and set up any required environment to ensure that JAX-RS is loaded and enabled.

In your JAX-RS handler class, have the environment inject an EntityManager from a JPA2 provider like Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc - whatever Heroku offers on their Java appserver.

Create an instance of your entity model class. Populate it with the JSON data you received as an argument to your JAX-RS method, either as a raw string, or [decoded into an object using something like Jersey's JSON support](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json).

Persist the new instance of the entity model class using the entity manager, flush, and commit the entity manager session.

The details of all this are quite dependent on the specifics of the application server and runtime environment provided by Heroku. Java EE 6 is a "standard" in the same way that railroad tracks are a "standard" .... which standard do you want, you've got seven to choose from.

### If Heroku just provides a servlet container:

You can BYO tools.

You won't necessarily have any sort of injection, but you can plug in your own with tools like Guice, or a portable CDI implementation like Weld.

You could quite happily use Jersy (for JAX-RS) and Hibernate. Or use PgJDBC directly via the servlet container's connection pool.

You can even write your own web service call methods directly as servlets, but that way lies madness.